# SQL query to return rows with the value of a column above a certain minimum value depending on category?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have for example these 2 tables:

table1:

```
item       category     rating
------     --------     ------
table      furniture      6
chair      furniture      5
sofa       furniture      7
bed        furniture      4
apple      food           7
banana     food           6
spinach    food           9
almonds    food           8
happiness  feeling        7
compassion feeling        6
love       feeling        8
admiration feeling        7
```

and table2:

```
category     minimum_rating
--------     --------------
furniture          6 
food               8
feeling            7
```

and taking into consideration that the value minimum_rating for each category would be revised each month, so it would change... How would I query table1 in relation to table2 so that it would take the value of minimum_rating for that category of the item and return only those items in table1 with a rating equal or above the minimum rating? In this case the query would be expected to return:

```
item       category     rating
------     --------     ------
table      furniture      6
sofa       furniture      7
spinach    food           9
almonds    food           8
happiness  feeling        7
love       feeling        8
admiration feeling        7
```

Thanks a lot for your knowleadgeable input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a `JOIN` on both the table like below. You can probably as well say `t1.rating = t2.minimum_rating`

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.category = t2.category
where t1.rating >= t2.minimum_rating;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rahul and @kl78 since both of your answers were almost indentical and correct. I think stackoverflow enforces to accept only one as the "most correct" because he kept the column naming given in the example and also posted the answer 10 seconds earlier ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A simple join should do the job:

```
Select a.* from table1 as a
 inner join table2 as b on a.furniture = b.furniture and a.rating >=     b.minimum_rating;
```